# Is there anything preventing a wizard from using a staff of healing?

Tags: magic-items, wizard, healing, pathfinder-2e

The [Staff of Healing](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=357) has a lot of spells I wouldn't expect to see a wizard cast - Regenerate, Heal, etc, but I don't see anything in the rules on staves that precludes a wizard from using it.

Is any staff usable by any caster?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## To cast a spell from a staff, it has to be on your spell list

The rules for [Casting a spell from a staff](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=749) spell out the requirements to cast from a staff. The relevant part of these requirements:

> You can Cast a Spell from a staff only if you have that spell on your spell list, are able to cast spells of the appropriate level, and expend a number of charges from the staff equal to the spell’s level.

Also, you need to be the one who prepared the staff to cast from it:

> A staff gains charges when someone prepares it for the day. The person who prepared a staff can expend the charges to cast spells from it.

To [prepare a staff](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=751), you also need at least one of the spells the staff can cast on your spell list.

> You can prepare a staff only if you have at least one of the staff’s spells on your spell list.

The list of [Arcane spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?Tradition=1) (Wizards are arcane tradition casters) does not contain "Heal" or "Stabilize" (The spells that a generic Staff of Healing can cast), so the Wizard could neither prepare the staff nor cast spells from it.

Comment: Dangit how do I keep missing these little bits of rules, thank you

Comment: PF2 has a lot of rules, one is bound to miss some of them :D